# Как принять настройки из preference

Tags: android

У меня есть множество пунктов настроек в preference , вроде чекбокса и выбора размера текста. Как мне принять и применить все настройки?

Comment: Вы рассчитываете что существует метод типа `appyAllMyPreferencesToAllMyViews(boolean apply)`? Если да, то такого метода нет. Надо вручную всё это делать.

Comment: Нет, я вручную изначально хотел. Но не знаю как этого сделать.

Comment: `textView.setTextSize(pref.getInt("pref_key_text_size", 21))`?